# PdfBox text width greater than page width

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am working with PdfBox. I have a very long string, i want to write that string to Pdf file.
I want to check if the length of the string is greater than page width.

```
PDPage page = new PDPage();
page.setMediaBox(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
PDSimpleFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
float titleWidth = (font.getStringWidth(pdfLine) ) / 1000 * fontSize;
int width = PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4.getWidth();

if(titleWidth > width)
{
 //do something
}
```

The problem that I am getting is that the width is not correct. When I get the width I divide the string into parts of that length so that it is within the page width. I guess I need to convert the width of the text into the length of the Java string that the page can hold. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: And, er, _what_ problem are you actually having with it?

Comment: the problem that i am getting is that width is not correct. when i get the width i divide the string into parts of that length so that it is with in the page width. I guess i need to convert the width of the text into the length of the java string that the page can hold.

But i dont know how to do it.

Comment: You mean your calculated titeWidth is not correct, or the width variable in your code above?